# excel formula or macro to automatically convert long form data to wide form

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to have function that will change the long form of data to wide form. This means that each level of factor will be in separate column in excel.

I want to automate this process so that every time I do not need to do a lot of copy and paste when number of levels of a factor is very high.

Something like the following :

[image]

Comment: Have you considered a pivot table?

Comment: @chuff, thanks, downside is we can not create xy scatter plot (I am using excel 2003, not tried in 2007 or 2010)

Comment: Just for your information (and understanding that it may not be helpful to your situation), although you cannot create a scatter plot using the pivot table as the data range for the chart, you can make a plot using a data range of cell references to the pivot table. For example, if your summary data above was a pivot table result, you could replicate the data below with `=F3` in F11, `=F4` in F12, etc., and create the chart using the new range.

Answer (score 2):

Use the transpose function and apply it to the E-H range with Ctrl + Shift + Enter (Array function). If the size grows you just select the bigger range E2:xx And again apply the formula with Ctrl + Shift + Enter.

Automating works with a VBA code like:

```
Range("J5:O13").Select
Selection.FormulaArray = "=TRANSPOSE(R[-3]C[-8]:R[13]C[-6])"
```